# How to use Konva.js with the Android platform?

Tags: konvajs, konva, vue-konva

currently I'm developing a project using Konva.js and Vue-Konva.js. In the future, there's a new requirement for the project to run on the Android platform. To achieve this, I have a few ideas:

1. Develop an app version: Since Konva.js doesn't support a React Native version, this option seems  not to be working.
2. Develop a WebView version: I will develop the new version with React. But I'm not sure if all features can be implemented this way.
3. Explore other libraries or tools.

I'd like to ask if my ideas are correct or if there are other suggested approaches. Additionally, I'm curious if there are more in-depth insights regarding the three points mentioned above. Thank you for the help!